# Hash Element of Array of arrays

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I want "testhash" to be a hash, with an key of "hashelm", which contains an array or an array.

I do this:

```
$testhash{hashelm}=(
        ["1A","1B"],
        ["2A","2B"]
);

print Dumper(%testhash);
```

But I get this as output:

```
$VAR1 = 'hashelm';
$VAR2 = [
          '2A',
          '2B'
        ];
```

I would expect something more like:

```
$VAR1 = 
   hashlelm => (
        [
          '1A',
          '1B'
        ];
        [
          '2A',
          '2B'
        ];
   )
```

What am I missing??
I've been using perl for **years** and this one really has me stumped!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashes can only store scalar values; `(["1A", "1B"], ["2A", "2B"])` is a list value. When evaluated in this scalar context, you only get the last item in the list, namely `["2A", "2B"]`. You need to store a *reference* to a list value in the hash:

```
$testhash{hashelm} = [ ["1A","1B"], ["2A","2B"] ];
```

Read more in the perl documentation on [list value constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors).

Comment: Wow - after all this time - never really groked the difference between a list and an array. The part about the hash storing only a scalar value makes a lot of sense, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
$testhash{hashelm}=[
        ["1A","1B"],
        ["2A","2B"]
];
```

You have to use the square brackets for an anonymous array.